# Digital Signature on file gone after download from website

Tags: asp.net, download, digital-signature, authenticode

I have developed a software application and digitally signed my installer with an Authenticode certificate obtained from Verisign (now Symantec).  I signed the installer (.exe) using the signtool.exe utility that comes with Visual Studio.  When I run the installer it now says my company name as the publisher instead of "unknown" which was my objective....success!

I then posted the installer file on my website for distribution to my customers.  The file is served by an asp:button that executes the following code when clicked:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=CP11Full_x86.exe");

Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/Software/ContainmentPlanner/Files/CP11Full_x86.exe"));

HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

When I download the installer file from my website and run it the publisher field says "unknown"!!!
I then copied the file directly from my web server to my computer using an FTP client and the downloaded file HAD THE SIGNATURE (i.e. did not show publisher: unknown), so apparently the file on the web server is fine.  It must be something about the process of downloading the file via the website that strips or invalidates the digital signature.  I tried both Firefox and IE and got the same result.

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Have you compared the files bitwise?

Answer (score 2):

It could be that some HTML is getting written into the response stream, corrupting the download.  Try this:
Before your call to TransmitFile, add

```
Response.Clear();
```

After the call to TransmitFile, add

```
Response.SuppressContent = "true";
```